# The "pythonic" way for expanding a list

Tags: python, list

I have one list representing point in time of a change, and another one of values:

```
indexes_list = [5, 6, 8, 9, 12, 15]
# [ 5  6  8  9 12 15]
values_list = [i * 10 for i in range(6)]
# [ 0 10 20 30 40 50]
```

I want to create the "full" list, which in the above example is:

```
expanded_values = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 20, 20, 30, 40, 40, 40, 50, 50, 50]
# [ 0  0  0  0  0  0 10 20 20 30 40 40 40 50 50 50]
```

I wrote something, but it feels wrong and I guess there is a better, more pythonic way of doing that:

```
result = []
for i in range(len(values_list)):
    if i == 0:
        tmp = [values_list[i]] * (indexes_list[i] + 1)
    else:
        tmp = [values_list[i]] * (indexes_list[i] - indexes_list[i - 1])
    result += tmp
# result = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 20, 20, 30, 40, 40, 40, 50, 50, 50]
```

Comment: what is the logic behind extended list?

Comment: These array represent a state after an event, the extended array is the state in any point in time. You can assume the values are always rising/decreasing.

Comment: Why isn't values_array just the simpler: `values_array = [i * 10 for i in range(6)]`?

Comment: BTW, if your code works why do you search for _pythonic way_?

Comment: @ARMAN readability mostly

Comment: @DarrylG Just because of lots of retries, I will edit this

Comment: pythonic way is the exact opposite of readability

Comment: This isn't a `numpy` task.  Drop the numpy tag, and don't call the list an array.

Comment: @hpaulj Done. But actually, the best answer in my opinion used numpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
indexes_array = [5, 6, 8, 9, 12, 15]
values_array = [i * 10 for i, _ in enumerate(range(6))]

diffs = indexes_array[:1] + [j - i for i, j in zip(indexes_array, indexes_array[1:])]
res = [v for i, v in zip(diffs, values_array) for _ in range(i)]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 20, 20, 30, 40, 40, 40, 50, 50, 50]
```

As an alternative, you could use the [pairwise](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) recipe with a twist:

```
from itertools import tee


def pairwise(iterable, prepend):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    yield prepend, next(b, None)
    yield from zip(a, b)


indices = [5, 6, 8, 9, 12, 15]
values = [i * 10 for i, _ in enumerate(range(6))]

differences = [second - first for first, second in pairwise(indices, prepend=0)]
res = [v for i, v in zip(differences, values) for _ in range(i)]

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 20, 20, 30, 40, 40, 40, 50, 50, 50]
```

Finally if you are doing numerical work I advise that you use [numpy](https://numpy.org/), as below:

```
import numpy as np

indices = [5, 6, 8, 9, 12, 15]
values = [i * 10 for i, _ in enumerate(range(6))]


differences = np.diff(indices, prepend=0)
res = np.repeat(values, differences).tolist()
print(res)
```

Comment: The last one (numpy) is exactly what I wanted (even though it doesn't print the exact wanted result), thanks!

Comment: What did you get? I verified and it gives the output required

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that it is pythonic to use the appropriate library, which in this case is [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/):

```py
import pandas as pd

indexes_array = [5, 6, 8, 9, 12, 15]
values_array = [i * 10 for i in range(6)]

series = pd.Series(values_array, indexes_array).reindex(
    range(indexes_array[-1] + 1), method='backfill')

series
```

```
0      0
1      0
2      0
3      0
4      0
5      0
6     10
7     20
8     20
9     30
10    40
11    40
12    40
13    50
14    50
15    50
dtype: int64
```

See the `reindex` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
indexes_array = [5, 6, 8, 9, 12, 15]
# [ 5  6  8  9 12 15]
values_array = [i * 10 for i, _ in enumerate(range(6))]
# [ 0 10 20 30 40 50]

result = []
last_ind = 0
zipped = zip(indexes_array, values_array)

for ind, val in zipped:
    count = ind - last_ind
    last_ind = ind
    for i in range(count):
        result.append(val)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 20, 20, 30, 40, 40, 40, 50, 50, 50]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
indexes_array = [5, 6, 8, 9, 12, 15]
values_array = [i * 10 for i, _ in enumerate(range(6))]
output=[]
for x in range(len(indexes_array)):
  if x ==0:
    output.extend([values_array[x]]*indexes_array[x])
  else:
    output.extend([values_array[x]]*(indexes_array[x]-indexes_array[x-1]))

print(output)
```

The output is :

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 20, 20, 30, 40, 40, 40, 50, 50, 50]
```